# Vertical align text inside of list item

Tags: css, inline, vertical-alignment, listitem

```html
<ul>
  <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
   <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px;">[%code1%]</div></li>
  <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
   <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px;">[%code2%]</div></li>
  <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
   <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px;">[%code3%]</div></li>
  <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
   <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px;">[%code4%]</div></li>
</ul>
```

how can I vertical align text on list item, without using display: flex; align-items-center. And only inline css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

*without using display: flex; align-items-center. And only inline css.*

```html
<ul style="list-style:none">
  <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px;">
    <span style="font-size:40px; vertical-align: middle;margin-right:10px">&#8226</span>
    <span style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px; vertical-align: middle;">  [%code1%]</span>
  </li>
  <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px;">
    <span style="font-size:40px; vertical-align: middle;margin-right:10px">&#8226</span>
    <span style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px; vertical-align: middle;">  [%code1%]</span>
  </li>
    <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px;">
    <span style="font-size:40px; vertical-align: middle;margin-right:10px">&#8226</span>
    <span style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px; vertical-align: middle;">  [%code1%]</span>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
  <ul>
    <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
     <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">[%code1%]</div></li>
    <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
     <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">[%code2%]</div></li>
    <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
     <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">[%code3%]</div></li>
    <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
     <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">[%code4%]</div></li>
  </ul>
```

Theoretically this will change the `vertical-align` style. The problem is the difference between your `<li>` and inner `<div>` `font-size`. Try [adding a custom <li> bullet](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) to your list instead

Answer (score 0):

Even if you need to use inline CSS, I think you can simplify your code a bit and take advantage of the cascade by adding some of those properties to the `<ul>`.

There's probably more than one way to do this, but I added `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to the `<div>`s...

```html
<ul style="color: black; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 32px;">
  <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px;">
    <div style="font-size: 17px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">[%code1%]</div>
  </li>
  <li style="margin: 0 0 23px 0;">
    <div style="font-size: 17px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">[%code2%]</div>
  </li>
  <li style="margin: 0 0 23px 0;">
    <div style="font-size: 17px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">[%code3%]</div>
  </li>
  <li style="margin: 0 0 23px 0;">
    <div style="font-size: 17px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">[%code4%]</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add These properties to div

```
display: inline;
    line-height: 2;
    vertical-align: bottom;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 23px; font-size: 32px;">
   <div style="font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black; font-size: 17px;display:inline;line-height:2;vertical-align:bottom;">[%code1%]</div>
</li>
  
  
  
</ul>
```